# I want to use the IVT to show that there is a root of $e^x=3-2x$ in the interval $(0,1).$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots

This question has plagued me for over a year and this type of mistake has shown up three times in my Calculus 1 class this year.

I would like to use the IVT to show that there is a root of $e^x=3-2x$ in the interval $(0,1).$

So first, I think I would move all the terms to one side of $=$:

But, do I subtract $e^x$ from both sides or $-3 + 2x$ from both sides? And why?  Because when I solve for zero, I get $-1.7$ in one instance and $1.7$ in the other.

EDIT: Thanks so much for the responses-- unfortunately I'm still confused. f(1) in one situation is not the same as f(1) in the other situation. I've graphed both forms and the graphs are different meaning they are different functions, right? They have the same zeros, yes, but my question is why are these different functions. Shouldn't they be equivalent if I do the same algebra to both sides of the equation? e^x does not = -e^x. It seems like what I'm asking and what you all are answering are two different things and I can't currently tell where my disconnect is. You all seem to agree with one another but I can't make that leap because I'm still stuck, I believe, with a question about the basic algebra of the situation.

Comment: Please include your work in each attempt.  If you subtract $3-2x$ from both sides, you'll find the both efforts agree.  Else you can **add** $-(3-2x) =-3+2x$ to both sides,

Comment: The solutions of $f(x)=0$ are clearly precisely the same solutions as those of $-f(x)=0$. It makes no difference if you define $f(x)=e^x-3+2x$ or $f(x)=3-2x-e^x$. I'm not sure what you mean about $1.7$ and $-1.7$.

Comment: Snaw, but the OP subtracted -3 + 2x, from $e^x$.  I've covered the sign error, and the mistake.

Comment: Snaw and amWhy (thank you!)

Ok, the original equation is e^x=3-2x. 

In my first attempt, I subtract e^x from both sides and get 0=3-2x-e^x 

In an alternative attempt beginning with the same equation, I subtract 3 from both sides and add 2x to get e^x-3+2x=0. The signs for the terms are opposite in each attempt.

Comment: f(1) in each case is different (with e=~2.71) positive/negative 1.71 depending on the signs of the terms

Comment: Left minus right: $$e^0-3+2\cdot0=-2<0$$ $$e^1-3+2\cdot1\approx1.718>0$$ $$\therefore\quad\exists x\in(0,1),\quad e^x-3+2\cdot x=0$$ Right minus left: $$3-2\cdot0-e^0=2>0$$ $$3-2\cdot1-e^1\approx-1.718<0$$ $$\therefore\quad\exists x\in(0,1),\quad 3-2\cdot x-e^x=0$$ They are saying the same thing.

Comment: Consider instead that the search for the zero of function $f(x)=e^x-(3-2x)=e^x+2x-3$